# Excel - check if number range is within another number range or only partially within

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using the formula below to check if a value is within a set of ranges per person on which is working fine.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,(Q9>=$B$2:$B$5)*(Q9<=$C$2:$C$5)),"NONE")
```

However I want to know how to adjust the formula to not just check a value but to check if an entire range falls within the range of a person. and to check if it only partially falls within a range or even if it falls within the range of two people and how much falls within that range

[excelsnip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZpyG.png)

Please let me know if there is a way to accomplish this test with a formula.

Tried adjusting the formula but no luck.

Comment: Your formula can't be related to your screenshot, when it doesn't show cell `Q9`...